# zend framework & google analytics data

Tags: zend-framework, google-analytics

How can I use zend framework to export google analytics data into my application? I've used other Zend_Service_GData before, but can't find any documentation how to apply it to google analytics?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official library for google analytics, but you could have a look at: 
http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Gdata_Analytics+-+Daniel+Hartmann

It hasn't been updated in a while, but I've used it without problems before.